# Linking.openURL doesn't work with the first click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
useEffect(()=>{
   dispatch(getList())
}, [])

onPress=()=>{
  dispatch(myUrlaction(id))
   if(url){
  Linking.openURL(url)
   }
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={onPress}
      >
        <Text>Press Here</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
   }
```

My question is OpenUrl doesn't open the link on first click , since it waits for the network response from my dispatch to be completed. it needs a second click. onPress function is dispatching at the same time opening the url. Somehow i need to wait until it finishes.

Comment: Where do you get the url variable from? What happens when you dispatch myUrlAction with and without an ID? Usually you'll do something async in your first useEffect, set the value you get back into state, and then have a second useEffect that reacts to the state change. Until you have a value for url you should show a loading state in the button.

Comment: @Abe the url is a redux state from  dispatch(myUrlaction(id)) action

Comment: myUrlaction updates url state, with onPress i am dispatching and using the response from dispatch  opening a url , so it needs a second click to work

Comment: Dispatch doesn't send a response though, you will need to select state to get the result of the dispatch